# Solution for the roots of $x^4+x^2+1=0$

Tags: roots

Is this solution to find the roots of $x^4+x^2+1=0$ correct?

$x^4+x^2+1=0$

$x^4+2x^2+1-x^2=0$

$(x^2+1)^2-x^2=0$

$[(x^2+1)-x][(x^2+1)+x]=0$

$(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)=0$

For this equation to be true, either $(x^2-x+1)=0$ or/and $(x^2+x+1)=0$.

Using the quadratic formula, I got

$x=\frac{1\pm{\sqrt{3}i}}{2}$

and

$x=\frac{-1\pm{\sqrt{3}i}}{2}$

Are these values of x under the set of complex numbers the roots of $x^4+x^2+1=0$?

To answer this, I tried to check my answers using a computing website. According to the website, here are the solutions:

[image]

Comment: Yes. They are four roots for given equation.

Comment: @MAK can you just substitute your found values back to the original polynomial to see it becomes $0$? It's just another notation of these. [wolframalpha for $(-1)^{(1/3)}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Re%28%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29%2BIm%28%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29*I)

Answer (score 1):

Given equation
\begin{eqnarray}
x^4+x^2+1=0
\end{eqnarray}
Suppose $x^2=y$ then $y^2+y+1=0$
using  quadratic formula we have
\begin{eqnarray}
y=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}\\
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
Thus~~~~~~~~ x^2=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}\\
\Rightarrow  ~~x=\pm\sqrt\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}
\end{eqnarray}